# Union between optional and non-optional tables

Tags: sql, scala, join, union, slick

I have two queries that select records where a union needs to be taken, one of which is a left join and one of which is a regular (i.e. inner) join.

Here's the left join case:

```
def regularAccountRecords = for {
      (customer, account) <- customers joinLeft accounts on (_.accountId === _.accountId) // + some other special conditions
} yield (customer, account)
```

Here's the regular join case:

```
def specialAccountRecords = for {
  (customer, account) <- customers join accounts on (_.accountId === _.accountId) // + some other special conditions
} yield (customer, account)
```

Now I want to take a union of the two record sets:

```
regularAccountRecords ++ specialAccountRecords
```

Obviously this doesn't work because in the regular join case it returns `Query[(Customer, Account),...]` and in the left join case it returns `Query[(Customer, Rep[Option[Account]]),...]` and this results in a Type Mismatch error.

Now, If this were a regular column type (e.g. `Rep[String]`) I could convert it to an optional via the `?` operator (i.e. `record.?`) and get `Rep[Option[String]]` but using it on a table (i.e. the accounts table) causes:

```
Error:(62, 85) value ? is not a member of com.test.Account
```

How do I work around this issue and do the union properly?

Comment: i have no idea if this will work but can you try account.map(_.?) on the normal join?

Comment: Nope, compiler errors out saying "value ? is non a member of com.typesafe...TableQuery[com...Account]." Good thought though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like this is what the '?' projection is for but I didn't realize it because I disabled the `optionEnabled` option in the Codegen. Here's what your codegen extension is supposed to look like:

```
class MyCodegen extends SourceCodeGenerator(inputModel) {
    override def TableClass = new TableClassDef {
        override def optionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use implicit classes to tack this thing onto the generated TableClass yourself. Here is how that would look:

```
implicit class AccountExtensions(account:Account) {
    def ? = (Rep.Some(account.id), account.name).shaped.<>({r=>r._1.map(_=> Account.tupled((r._2, r._1.get)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))
}
```

> NOTE: be sure to check the field ordering, depending on how this
>   projection is done, the union query might put the ID field in the wrong
>   place in the output, use
>   `println(query.result.statements.headOption)` to debug the output
>   SQL to be sure.

Once you do that, you will be able to use account.? in the yield statement:

```
def specialAccountRecords = for {
  (customer, account) <- customers join accounts on (_.accountId === _.accountId) 
} yield (customer, account.?)
```

...and then you will be able to unionize the tables correctly

```
regularAccountRecords ++ specialAccountRecords
```

I really wish the Slick people would put a note on how the '?' projection is useful in the documentation beyond the vague statement 'useful for outer joins'.